# SageMaker fails when trying to add Lifecycle Configuration for keeping custom environments persistent after restart

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I want to create environment in SageMaker on AWS with miniconda, and make it available as kernels in Jupyter when I restart the session. But the SageMaker keep failing.

I followed the instructions found in here:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sagemaker-lifecycle-script-timeout/

basically it says:
*"Create a custom, persistent Conda installation on the notebook instance's Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS) volume: Run the on-create script in the terminal of an existing notebook instance. This script uses Miniconda to create a separate Conda installation on the EBS volume (/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/). Then, run the on-start script as a lifecycle configuration to make the custom environment available as a kernel in Jupyter. This method is recommended for more technical users, and it is a better long-term solution."*

I run this on-create.sh script on the terminal on Jupyter:

on-create.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'
unset SUDO_UID
# Install a separate conda installation via Miniconda
WORKING_DIR=/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-environments
mkdir -p "$WORKING_DIR"
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.6.14-Linux-x86_64.sh -O "$WORKING_DIR/miniconda.sh"
bash "$WORKING_DIR/miniconda.sh" -b -u -p "$WORKING_DIR/miniconda" 
rm -rf "$WORKING_DIR/miniconda.sh"

# Create a custom conda environment
source "$WORKING_DIR/miniconda/bin/activate"
KERNEL_NAME="conda-test-env"
PYTHON="3.6"
conda create --yes --name "$KERNEL_NAME" python="$PYTHON"
conda activate "$KERNEL_NAME"
pip install --quiet ipykernel
# Customize these lines as necessary to install the required packages
conda install --yes numpy
pip install --quiet boto3
EOF
```

and it creates the "conda-test-env" environment as expected.

Then I add the on-start.sh as lifestyle configuration:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'
unset SUDO_UID
source "/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-environments/miniconda/bin/activate"
conda activate conda-test-env
python -m ipykernel install --user --name "conda-test-env" --display-name "conda-test-env"

# Optionally, uncomment these lines to disable SageMaker-provided Conda functionality.
# echo "c.EnvironmentKernelSpecManager.use_conda_directly = False" >> /home/ec2-user/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
# rm /home/ec2-user/.condarc
EOF
```

then I update the instance with the new configuration,
and when I start my notebook instance, after few minutes it fails.

I'll appreciate any help.